# Design Runnables that are interruptable

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it sufficient to wrap contents of run method inside a while loop that checks if THread is interrupted for making any Thread interruptable

```
public void run () {
  while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
     do something.
  }    
}
```

Comment: Note that not all code can be interrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does a thread support its own interruption? This depends on what
>   it's currently doing. If the thread is frequently invoking methods
>   that throw InterruptedException, it simply returns from the run method
>   after it catches that exception.

[Reference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

For a example if your thread goes for sleep bettween work then it is better to catch `InterruptedException`.

```
public void run(){
 while(true)
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
        return;
    }
}
```

If your thread runs for long time you can check periodically invoke Thread.interrupted, which returns true if an interrupt has been received.

Comment: Quoi, this is for the case when we shutdown Exectuors from a master class and this sends InterruptException to running threads. The Threads need to stop acting on that Exception

Comment: Once INterruptedException is caught in run(), we can return. BUt If run also calls some methods where there is catch(Exception e) blocks, will this still work if I just throw e from such methods from inside THread and finally return from run catch block.

Comment: Its depend upon Thread works. If thread goes for sleep and certainly your `Exectuors` has shutdown then there would be odd condition that thread will raise a `Interrupted Exception `

Comment: That's typical of thread interruption management. (C++) boost interruption points mention the same way of functionning where the thread can "realize" an external agent has signaled it for extinction, only on "interruption points". Which the doc says are yield points or syncro points. It is not specific to Java and that comes form the fact that the OS rarely provides an interface to "kill threads". I think an old version of Windows did, but it doesn't exist anymore. So you have to cooperatively check in the thread logic if you need to exit yourself.

Comment: In my case, database operations mostly happen in meothds other than run. If shutdown sent an Interrupt while it was establishing some connection , will it be considered equivalent to sleep ?

Comment: I don't know, but if your database routines are not Java there is a huge chance that the internal implementation of the "sleeping points/sync points" will not do the interruption check and not throw the needed exception. But maybe your database framework is pure Java and will support that... no idea. You are better to use timeouts I think, to get out of the thrid-party zones and regularly come back to a sync point you control.

Answer (score 0):

interrupted() is static method to check the current thread is interrupted or not. isInterrupted() is an instance to check the Thread objects called on.
For Present Thread use

```
if(!(Thread.interrupted())){//do something}
```

When Thread object called  use `if(myThread.isInterrupted()){//do something
}`